# not putting id into variable

Tags: php, mysql

The purpose of this script is to get ProductID for the Product that the user has entered into a form, the ID of the order that has been created in a previous script and then put these 2 values into the order_line_item table.

I have identified that the error occurs because there is no value in variable called '$db_productid' and then when I insert this value into the database it tries to look for a product with that ID that it can link to but there is no product with an ID of 0 so it returns the following error:

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`the_shop`.`order_line_item`, CONSTRAINT `order_line_item_ibfk_1`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`ProductID`) REFERENCES `product` (`ProductID`) ON DELETE
>   CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

this is my script:

```
  if (isset($_GET['submit1'])) {
    $dblastid = $_SESSION['lastid'];
    $db_product_name = $_GET['product_name'];

    $query = "SELECT ProductID FROM product WHERE Product_Name = '$db_product_name'";
    $result = mysql_query($query)
            or die(mysql_error());
    $fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $db_productid = $fetch['ProductID'];
    $lastid = $_SESSION['lastid'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO `the_shop`.`order_line_item`(
`OrderID` ,
`ProductID`
)
VALUES (
'$lastid', '$db_productid')";
    $result = mysql_query($query)
            or die(mysql_error());
}
```

upon further debugging I have discovered that the string that the user inputs into the form does appear in '$db_product_name' and a product with this name is on the database in the product table

Comment: you talk about `$dbcustomerid`, but that variable doesn't exist in your code snippet.

Comment: I meant $db_productid sorry

Comment: in that case, make sure your query actually RETURNS at least one row of data... and note that you're wide open for [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: Just did an echo on $fetch[ProductID]

and there is nothing in there

Comment: I will be dealing with the SQL injection holes once the rest of my website is working. Hopefully it wont take lone but my 1st goal is to get the website working with full functionality.

Comment: wrong... you deal with SQL injection FIRST. the other way around is a bank saying "naw, we don't need a vault, we'll just leave all the money sitting in a pile in the lobby. it'll be fine".

Comment: I didn't mean it will be released like that... I intend to get the website fully functioning but wouldn't release it until the security  flaws have been dealt with...

Answer (score 1):

For some reason my teacher gave the impression that we needed to insert variables like this

`.$db_username.` meaning that a username will be stored as the user intended it to be but with dots before and after the entry... anyway now inserting records without doing that and it works fine... will be funny for my teacher to see a website that works fine without doing that :)

Comment: `$x = 'a' . $b . 'c'` is concatenating the strings 'a' and 'c' with the value of the variable $b. doing `$x = "a{$b}c"` is the same thing